# Hook for Woocommerce Subscription address change

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, subscriptions

I'm using Woocommerce Subscriptions and currently the below action hook fires when you update your address on your Account Page > Edit Shipping (my-account/edit-address/shipping/) - HOWEVER it does not fire when you update your address on the Account > View subscription page > Edit Shipping (/my-account/edit-address/shipping/?subscription=62400).

```
function kidstir_email_customer_address( $user_id ) {
// do stuff
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_customer_save_address','kidstir_email_customer_address', 20 );
```

I've been looking for hours, and can't figure out why it's not firing, or how to get a notification that a subscription address has changed. Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Sad this is still an issue at the end of 2023.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of WooCommerce Subscriptions (2.0.9) does not call the woocommerce_customer_save_address hook in file class-wc-subscriptions-addresses.php

To solve my problem I edited this file (I know editing core is not advisable) to call the hook (doaction etc) on line 137.

Comment: Sad that this seems to still be an issue 7+ years later. Doesn't looks like there is a good solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [official documentation](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/) of the WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin, there is a `updated_users_subscriptions` hook.

Comment: Yes, I saw that thank you. It only fires when the following elements change

Comment: 'expiry_date'        
'failed_payments'    
 'end_date'            
'status'              
'completed_payments'  
 'failed_payments'     
 'suspension_count'

Answer (score 0):

We couldn't find a good solution that doesn't involve editing core/plugins, so we did this instead:

- force the checkbox to update all subscriptions to checked by default

```
// make the "update address on all active subscriptions" box checked by default
add_filter( 'wcs_update_all_subscriptions_addresses_checked', '__return_true' );
```

- hide the checkbox

```css
#update_all_subscriptions_addresses_field {
    display: none;
}
```

- modify the links to edit address in subscription to go to the general address edit screen

```
function customslug_subscription_actions( $actions, $subscription, $user_id ) {
    $actions['change_address']['url'] = '/my-account/edit-address/shipping/';
    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'wcs_view_subscription_actions', 'customslug_subscription_actions', 999, 3 );
```

It's not a great solution, but it's better than leaving things broken and confusing for users...

If having access to the `woocommerce_customer_save_address` hook is essential for your use case, but making individual subscription addresses editable is not, this might work for you too.